How do I make a Cloudwatch alarm for remaining database connections
I want to make a Cloudwatch alarm when "available connections" falls below a threshold.
This would be difference of DatabaseConnections and DBMaxConnections.
I specifically don't want to use just DatabaseConnections and compare to a static value, because this is an Aurora Serverless cluster, so the DBMaxConnections will fluctuate as the ACUs scale.
Is this possible?

You can combine multiple metrics in a math expression to e.g. divide one by the other and alarm when that value crosses 0.9 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html (or subtract one from the other and alarm if that value is below e.g. 10)
